# class Boo():pass var1 = Boo var1.x = 4 How is this possible

Tags: python

```
class Boo():
    pass

var1 = Boo
var1.x = 4
```

But there is no x in Boo, it was never declared! How is this possible?

--Edit--

Wow, this is mind blowing, you can do this!

Comment: because you don't have to declare members in python. you just created a new (class) variable for `Boo`

Comment: because code bro

Comment: You just declared it!

Comment: It should be `var1 = Boo()`

Comment: By default, Python objects have a mutable dictionary for storing attributes. You can assign whatever you want to it.

Comment: @Barmar: not if you define a class variable.

Comment: @barmar. It's probably what OP meant, but it doesn't have to be. OP's syntax is technically fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classes have a `__dict__` by default, precisely for this purpose (run-time assignment and modification of attributes).  Regular attribute assignment just puts the corresponding names and values values in there.

It's no different from setting it at class definition time, really:

```
>>> class Boo:
...     x = 1
...     
>>> Boo.y = 2
>>> Boo.__dict__
mappingproxy({'__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'Boo' objects>,
              '__doc__': None,
              '__module__': '__main__',
              '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'Boo' objects>,
              'x': 1,
              'y': 2})
```

This way, you can contribute methods and variables to classes after the class has already been defined, and it will effect pre-existing instances of that class.  If you hear of someone saying Python is a *dynamic* programming language, what you're seeing here is one aspect of what the term [dynamic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming_language) actually means in this context.